# XJC Generated Java Classes Missing Import Statement When Using Binding Declaration

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2, xjc

I am trying to use XJC to generate Java classes from a XML Schema and a bindings file. The bindings file is intended to generate a member of type InetAddress instead of String in the generated class.

I have the following:

### config.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsd:element name="config">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element name="ip" type="IPv4Address" />
        </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:simpleType name="IPv4Address">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            IPv4 address in the dotted-decimal notation.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>

    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:pattern value="((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

### configBindings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jxb:bindings version="2.0"
          xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="config.xsd" node="/xsd:schema" >
    <jxb:globalBindings>
        <jxb:javaType name="InetAddress" xmlType="IPv4Address" parseMethod="InetAddress.getByName" printMethod="getHostAddress" />
    </jxb:globalBindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Then, I run XJC with `xjc -b configBindings.xml config.xsd` which generates java code in the directory "generated".
However, while the type of member `ip` has been correctly bound to `InetAddress`, the file Config.java is missing an import statement for java.net.InetAddress. So when I try to compile Config.java or the adapter Adapter1.java I get several errors of this sort:

```
$ javac generated/Adapter1.java 
generated/Adapter1.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
    extends XmlAdapter<String, InetAddress>
                               ^
  symbol: class InetAddress
```

**Am I required to manually insert the needed import statements after running XJC? Is there no way to get XJC to do this for me automatically, even if I were to specify the needed packages in the binding file somehow?**

NOTE: I actually want to use my own adapter class to do this so that I can deal with the InetAddress exceptions properly, but this example makes the question a little easier to ask even if the generated code won't compile after manually adding the import statement because UnknownHostException is not dealt with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the fully qualified class name. You can't expect XJC to *guess* that you meant `java.net.InetAddress`.

Comment: Thanks. Never expected it to guess.